# How to Insert X Y to Geometry in Spring Boot and Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I use @query to Insert **X** **Y** to Geometry in Postgres. But it error.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name,SRID=4326;POINT(:x :y))", nativeQuery = true)   
@Transactional
void addSPCTY(@Param("name") String ten,@Param("x") String x,@Param("y") String y);
```

Error in Java: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near ;`

Please Help me. Tks all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without SRID , i think values should be in your sql (:name ,POINT(:x,:y)) like this.

Comment: I get error when run :  ERROR: function point(character varying, character varying) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like below:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = " insert into mypoints (name,geom) values (:name, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:x, :y), 4326)\\:\\:geography)", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
void addSPCTY(@Param("name") String ten, @Param("x") String x, @Param("y") String y);
```

Comment: Error when run:  function ST_SetSRID  (character varying, character varying) does not exist

Comment: it not work . Error : Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'